# changing theme of C# windows application

Tags: themes, c#-2.0, windows

in ASP we have so many ways to change theme .
but is there any way for chanigngthe whole theme of a windows application/?

Comment: what kind of windows application do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

By default a winform app will inherit windows theme but you can explicitly change some ui properties like color,font etc.

You can also consider moving to WPF for better and easy to implement UI.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, at least not easily.

But you could give WPF a try, you will need to upgrade to C# 3.0 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Some 3rd party component sets support theming.
Example : [Developer express](http://www.devexpress.com/)